# Volume group showing size incorrect

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

The problem i have is that my volume group size is much bigger than it possible could be.

I have a physical disk of 300Gb.

I initially created a volume group on sda1.  The size below is showing correctly what i set it up to be (93.1Gb)  I then extended vg1 onto sda4 - so the volume group size should be approx (93+176) 269Gb.

```
sudo lsblk
[sudo] password for production:
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 278.9G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  93.1G  0 part
│ ├─vg1-lv_root 252:0    0   4.7G  0 lvm  /
│ ├─vg1-lv_usr  252:1    0   9.3G  0 lvm  /usr
│ ├─vg1-lv_var  252:2    0  19.3G  0 lvm  /var
│ ├─vg1-lv_home 252:3    0   9.3G  0 lvm  /home
│ └─vg1-lv_tmp  252:4    0   4.7G  0 lvm  /tmp
├─sda2            8:2    0   9.3G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3            8:3    0   477M  0 part /boot
└─sda4            8:4    0   176G  0 part
sdb               8:16   0 278.9G  0 disk
└─sdb1            8:17   0 278.9G  0 part /mnt/cassandra
sdc               8:32   0 278.9G  0 disk
└─sdc1            8:33   0 278.9G  0 part /mnt/disk3
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

However, as we see below, its saying its 445Gb.

```
sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               vg1
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  12
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                5
Open LV               5
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               445.52 GiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              114053
Alloc PE / Size       12096 / 47.25 GiB
Free  PE / Size       101957 / 398.27 GiB
VG UUID               NQM1uq-XGDm-I893-rXQk-Ex8y-Dw7W-CI2HQk
```

Here is the output of 'fdisk /dev/sda'

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 278.9 GiB, 299439751168 bytes, 584843264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xbd0bc5dd

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 195311615 195309568 93.1G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda2       565311488 584841215  19529728  9.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       195311616 196288511    976896  477M 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       196288512 565311487 369022976  176G 8e Linux LVM
```

sudo pvs

```
[sudo] password for production:
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda1  vg1  lvm2 a--  269.56g 222.31g
  /dev/sda4  vg1  lvm2 a--  175.96g 175.96g
```

Ubuntu version

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

What's the best method to fix this issue?

Comment: What does `sudo pvs` say? It will display the LVM physical volums and the volume groups to which they are allocated.

Comment: @AlexP added above, 2nd last section.

Comment: Well then, LVM has a wrong idea of the size of `sda1`. Try `sudo pvresize /dev/sda1`.

Comment: AlexP - you nailed it.  After pvresize

    PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
      /dev/sda1  vg1  lvm2 a--   93.13g  45.88g
      /dev/sda4  vg1  lvm2 a--  175.96g 175.96g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well then, LVM has a wrong idea of the size of sda1. Try:

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 0):

Running pvresize against all PVs that are seen by the pvs command also works for RHV using FV or ISCSI which uses LVM.  I just had to log in to one of the RHV-H servers recently because one on the VMs was forcibly paused due to what it thought was a lack of space and run pvresize on all the PVs which fixed the issue.

This is also a good and very safe fix on ISCSI disks.

This can sometimes occur if there is disruptions in the ISCSI host where your ISCSI shares come from on in the network between ISCSI "client" (uses shares) and the ISCSI "server" (has the actual disks sharing out ISCSI LUNs).